# How to set root route when added index.html to public folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a rails 4 app on heroku and have put index.html file to public folder(I try to use ionic app as mobile website). Now the root address serves this index.html file instead of root set in routes.rb. how do I change it back? And How to link to that index.html then?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your web server (not app server) it may be configured to look in the `public` directory by default before passing the request to the app server. If that is the case you will need to adapt that before continuing.

Create a controller such as `PublicController` and add a `index` action. Then copy your `index.html` file to the directory `app/views/public` and if you wish add a erb file extension. You may wish to skip using a layout which will by default be `application.html.erb`, if that is the case in your `PublicController` you can add `layout false, only: :index` to skip using a layout for your file.

In routes set `root to: 'public#index` and it will now serve your file by default when the root url is hit.

Comment: Thanks, that is a valid answer but in the end I have moved all the files I have put in public/ to public/www/ (whole ionic www folder js, css, html etc) and then just link to host/www/ for mobile website.